# Doctrine 2 select entities with none or less than relations

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to find all rows with none or less than 3 relations. What would be the best approach for that?

I tried the following code with several different selects, having, joins  but I can't figure out how to do it the right way:

```
    $db = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
    $db->addSelect('COALESCE(COUNT(errors), 0) AS HIDDEN errorCount');
    $db->join('u.errors', 'errors');
    $db->where('u.field1 IS NULL AND u.field2 NOT LIKE \'\'');
    $db->having('errorCount < 3');
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to select rows which have 3 null fields in a table? its easy or im not sure i understand well the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COUNT` function is an aggregate function which will return a single result unless you instruct it to group by something.

```
$db = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$db->addSelect('COUNT(errors) AS HIDDEN errorCount');
$db->leftJoin('u.errors', 'errors');
$db->where('u.field1 IS NULL AND u.field2 NOT LIKE \'\'');
$db->having('errorCount < 3');
$db->groupBy('u');
```

Additionally, if you want to count the number of relations that may or may not exist use a `LEFT JOIN`. The count on these results will be `0` which is `< 3`.